# Do amount of Joule mean the quantity of surges or power of one surge?

Tags: power, mains, strip

There is such specification as amount of Joule for power strips.
What exactly do they mean, the quantity of surges it can withstand (in other words longevity of a strip) or how powerful a single surge can be?

Comment: Please link to the specific product in question and it’s data sheet if any.

Comment: @Jakob Halskov oh no, not gonna do that. I have already one question closed as this site isn't about product recommendation.

Comment: Probably both...

Comment: This question needs context.

Comment: @Andy aka too late as there are proper answers already, but it's about power strips that you may connect your home appliances to (PC, printer...)

Comment: No it's never too late to make your question accessible by providing context.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The joule rating is the maximum energy of a single voltage surge event as determined using a specific testing procedure. If the protection is is provided by a varistor, there is a correlation between the life of the varistor and the number of times that it experiences a transient that causes it to dissipate energy. However there does not seem to be a specification for that. When varistors fail, they basically explode spreading metal oxide all over if they are not shielded. If a varistor is installed inside a product, the practice is to cover it with a non-flammable insulating material to block the spread of debris. A varistor will provide protection above the maximum energy rating, but it can fail in the process. In that case, you simply throw the power strip away like you would a fuse. It has done its job and you replace it.

Comment: about maximum energy rating: do you mean if strip's specs tell about 100J energy level, actually it will stop surge of 400J and then die?

Comment: If the varistor is rated 100J and absorbs 400J in a short time, like a millisecond, it is likely to short circuit. That will result in additional energy that will melt or vaporize the varistor and likely trip the circuit breaker in the power strip and/or the breaker for the circuit it is attached to. In doing that, it is likely that all of the energy will be absorbed there rather than in the equipment attached to the power strip.

Answer (score 1):

The joule rating of a surge protector actually is related to both longevity and max capacity. The rating gives the amount of energy it can dissipate, whether that is during one surge or over several surges before it fails. When that rated amount of energy has been dissipated, the circuitry will have be worn out and most likely not be able to protect your devices anymore.

Here is a link to read a little bit more if you are curious.

[https://gagthesurge.com](https://gagthesurge.com/high-joules-rating-surge-protectors/)